# Elementary number theory -Divisibility 1

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For arbitrary integers $a, b$ and $c$. Prove or disprove:

If $a|c$ and $b|c$ then $(ab)|c $

My solution was

$c=ma$ & $c=nb$ for some $n,m\in \mathbb{Z}$

∴ we can say that $c=kab$

means $ab|c$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: No. 4 and 6 divide 12, but 24 does not. Even more: every positive integer is a counterexample: $c$ divided $c$, but $c^2$ does not divide $c \geq 2$.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that $c=ma$ and $c=nb$ for some $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}.$  However, that only imples that $ma=nb$, not the $c=kab$ that you suggested.  We need an expression with $ab$ and it doesn't look like we can get there from $ma=nb$ without making things more complex, so that gives a hint that maybe we should try proving it false.

It doesn't take long.  For a small example $a=b=c=2$ works.  For a less trivial one try mixing combinations of primes.  $2\cdot3$ and $2\cdot5$ both divide $2\cdot3\cdot5$, but does their product?

Comment: but if C=12, a=3 and b=4  then what is happening?

Comment: Good question. In general, what if $a$ and $b$ are coprime?

Comment: Remember that in order to disprove the statement, then you don't have to show it is impossible to find $a,b,c$ with the property.  You only have to show that the property fails in at least one case. 

As for "what is happening", think about what AnotherJohnDoe said above.  If $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, then you might consider where things are different.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument is not valid.

As a counter example, note that $4$ divides $12$ and $6$ divides $12$ but $6\times 4 = 24$  does not  divide $12$.